# String indices must be integers, not str exception while working with several files?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, io

I am extracting text from a directory full of pdfs. For this task I am using python's [textract](http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_package.html) module:

In:

```
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(input_directory, '*.pdf')):    
        parsed = process(filename ,method='tesseract', language = 'spa')
```

Out:

```
---> 31 get_ipython().magic(u'time transform_files(input_d, out_d)')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
   2156         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2157         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2158         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2159 
   2160     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2077                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2078             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2079                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2080             return result
   2081 

<decorator-gen-59> in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    186     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    187     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 188         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    189 
    190         if callable(arg):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.pyc in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)
   1174         if mode=='eval':
   1175             st = clock2()
-> 1176             out = eval(code, glob, local_ns)
   1177             end = clock2()
   1178         else:

<timed eval> in <module>()

<ipython-input-11-ddedab540f65> in transform_files(input_directory, output_directory)
     12 
     13         filename = os.path.basename(filename)
---> 14         texts = parsed['content']
     15         all_texts[filename] = texts
     16 

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I do not know why this is happening since, as the [documentation states](http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_package.html), `filename` must be a path, and actually it is just a path. I also tried to make a test with a single file as follows:

```
path = '/pathTo/PDF_FILE.pdf/'
text_ocr = textract.process(path, method='tesseract', language = 'spa')
```

And everything goes well. So my question is, why I am getting this: `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str` and how to apply `process` to `filename` correctly?.

**UPDATE**

I also tried to place the content into a dict:

```
parsed = process(filename ,method='tesseract', language = 'spa', encoding='utf8')
parsed = {"content": parsed}
filename = os.path.basename(filename)
```

Comment: The exception is in the line `texts = parsed['content']`, so `parsed` is a string and you're indexing it with another string. That appears to be in your code, so either `parsed` is not getting the value you expect, or you're doing something silly with it. The part of the code you've shown doesn't seem to be related to the error (except perhaps as the place `parsed` gets defined?). Did you mean to show more code?

Comment: thanks for the help @Blckknght ...Sure, hold on. I ommited it for space!.

Comment: I updated the question @Blckknght

Comment: Have you also checked the type of `parsed`? And which part in that documentation you linked states that the return value of `process` is a dict?

Comment: Thanks @UnholySheep , any idea of how to generate a dict from parsed?.

Comment: Short answer: You can't. It's a string and you don't seem to be interested in it being a dict anyway (as you only try to extract the "content"). What information would you expect to be in this dict anyway?

Comment: With `content`and `filename`. Just to rewrite them in a new file in a directory @UnholySheep .

Comment: But the `filename` is what you provide to the `process` function - why should it return the exact same value back? But if you really want to create a dict you can just define one yourself, e.g.: `parsed_dict = {"filename": filename, "content": parsed}`

Comment: @Blckknght I actually tried it. How can I write in a new file each processed pdf file?...

Comment: You have multiple variables of different types named "filename"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be chasing a lot of red herrings about the types of variables (e.g. `filename`) that are not at all related to your exception. At the bottom of your traceback, Python tells you exactly where the exception is happening:

```
<ipython-input-11-ddedab540f65> in transform_files(input_directory, output_directory)
     12 
     13         filename = os.path.basename(filename)
---> 14         texts = parsed['content']
     15         all_texts[filename] = texts
     16 

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

From the exception message, we can infer that `parsed` is a string, not a dictionary that has a `'content'` key. Looking at the earlier lines in your code, the `parsed` variable comes from the call to `process`. The documentation for `textract` that you linked to doesn't give me any reason to expect `process` to return anything other than a string. Her's the basic example they give, right up at the top of their page:

```
import textract
text = textract.process('path/to/file.extension')
```

The variable name `text` sure suggests that you get a string back!

So I think you just need to rewrite your loop:

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(input_directory, '*.pdf')):    
    texts = process(filename, method='tesseract', language='spa')
    filename = os.path.basename(filename)
    all_texts[filename] = texts
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!. I tried to create a dict, and apparently it worked. Nevertheless... I am getting an unicode exception: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)`. I updated the question with more details.

Comment: I am chekcing if by modifiying the `encoding` parameter of `process` I am able to finally make this `transform_files` function works...

Comment: That exception has nothing to do with your previous error. You might have better luck if you asked about it in a separate question. Especially with encoding issues, you should make sure to tag your question appropriately with *either* Python 3 or Python 2 (not both), since they handle Unicode differently.